# Use varbinary(max) to store HTML? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figureout the best solution to store html data in some of my tables and track the history of changes made to that HTML.  I read that text, ntext, etc are no longer supported for AFTER Triggers so I was thinking of using the varbinary(max) instead.  Has anyone used varbinary to store HTML?  I was planning on tracking the changes using a trigger to write off the history when the HTML is updated.

As always I greatly appreciate the input....the feedback I get is always great.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using varchar(max) would be more logical - it is made for textual data and you can us string processing functions with it.

Comment: What if the HTML is going to be bigger than 8000 bytes?

Comment: varchar(max) has a limit of 2 GB

Comment: Thanks Ray...was thinking it only had a 8000 character limit..appreciate the info.

Answer (score 2):

Why not varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) instead?